# Using App Script to generate a quiz with random numbers

Tags: google-apps-script, google-forms, google-form-quiz

I have written some app script code that creates a Google Form. The questions on the form contain random numbers e.g.

```
function question_1 () {
     var a = getRandomInt(1,10);
     var b = getRandomInt(1,10);

     var question_string = "What is " + a + " + " + b + '?';
     var ans = a + b;
     return [question_string, ans];
 }

function create_quiz () {
     var form = FormApp.create("Quiz");

     var item = form.addMultipleChoiceItem();
     q1 = question_1()

     var question = q1[0]
     var answer = q1[1]

     item.setTitle(question)
     item.setChoices([
          item.createChoice(answer), 
          item.createChoice(answer+1),
          item.createChoice(answer-1)
     ]);
}
```

I would like to set up the form so that the correct response goes along with the question, for example, adding something like

```
   item.setResponse(answer)
```

so that the quiz can be auto-graded after the student has completed the quiz.

Can anyone suggest what API calls I'd need to make (and where) to achieve this?

Comment: Use the form submit trigger, check the values, and validate in the triggered function. https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events#form-submit

Answer (score 0):

> UPDATE: On April 2017 Google [announced](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/) that now it's possible to create Google Forms quizzes programmatically.

---

At this time the Forms Service from Google Apps Script doesn't include a class/method to handle quiz responses. You could look for all the available classes and methods on [Forms Service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/)